# Unable to remove Ownership Protection within Azure to transfer domain to Godaddy

Tags: azure, dns, godaddy-api

I am unable to successfully remove Ownership Protection within the Azure Domain Manager. I keep getting an error - There was an error processing your request. Please try again. If the error continues contact support at 18006427676.

Without turning this off, I cannot successfully transfer my domain to godaddy :(

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: You may contact support directly?

Comment: Apparently I need to pay a support subscription to speak to them directly :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This needs support investigation. So, if you have a support plan, I request you file a support ticket, else please do let us know, we will try and help you get a one-time free technical support. In this case, could you send an email to AzCommunity[at]Microsoft[dot]com referencing this thread and your subscription id.